# Load gif until full page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, load

I'm using this for my site to display a loading gif until my page is loaded.

It's kinda working.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
     <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" />
     Loading...
</div>
```

But, the gif disappears to soon. My images aren't fully loaded yet when the loading gif disappears. How do I have to edit this code so it will show the loading gif until EVERYTHING is loaded on my page?

Comment: set the speed of fadeout

Comment: move the script in bottom of the page. Hopefully it will resolve.

Comment: Suresh, that worked wonderful! Post it as an answer and I'll make it my favorite!

Answer (score 3):

Like Arijit said, you can set a timer on the [`fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function

## DEMO

---

Or to show a **.gif** loader until image(s) are ready use this:

```
$(window).onbeforeload(function(){
//..Your code here..
});
```

Once the page is loaded and window is ready use this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
//..Your code here..
});
```

The `load` event will only trigger when the page is fully loaded, not just the DOM of the page.

You can also use image placeholders `onbeforeload` so it only shows placeholders instead of the image(s).

Once image(s) is loaded, placeholders will be replaced with the actual image(s).

---

My last alternative for you could be this plugin instead. [ImagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thx for your answer! But Suresh his solution worked also. Anyway, thanks for your time!:D

Comment: No problem! I am glad that you got an answer to your question, even if it was Suresh solution! ;-)