# How to show a loading gif image while a page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to load a gif image while my page loads. I tried something like this

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="content"> Html Content Here ... </div>
<style>
    div#content {
    display: none;
    }

div#loading {
    top: 200 px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 160px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/loading.gif) no-repeat;
    cursor: wait;
    }

</style>
<script>
      function preloader(){
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        }//preloader
        window.onload = preloader;
</script>
```

but it did not work. No gif image is being showing while the page reloads.

Comment: A lot of things could be going on here.  Are you sure the background image URL is correct?  Did you try putting an <img> tag with a hard-coded URL to check whether that's the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the background-image URL is correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load gif until full page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055493/load-gif-until-full-page-load)

Comment: I think you have to get your head around, how your page is constructed. If you are trying to render content of newsfeeds for example you can render the "preloader" when firing the request and unrender it when your server responds

Comment: yes i am sure background url is correct

Comment: The problem is not your background URL. It is your onLoad event. It will only fire if all elements in your body tag have loaded. So your loading icon gets displayed exactly 0ms.

Comment: best choice is to use spin.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you're doing will accomplish what you want. You are hiding and then immediately showing the image you want to show while the page loads? And then you are calling it after the page has already loaded. Try this:

```
function myOnload() {
    // You should pre-set the style in css for this element, you don't need to
    // explicitly show it. The element will be hidden on page load.
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}

// It's better practice to not override global onload state.
var old_onload = window.onload;

// Load your function.
window.onload = function() {
    myOnload();
    if (typeof(old_onload) === 'function') old_onload();
}
```